# laravel owen-it/laravel-auditing not update db

Tags: laravel

I'm working on laravel project and it uses caffeinated/modules. For a reason i need to track history of model value changes. So I tried owen-it/laravel-auditing(https://packalyst.com/packages/package/owen-it/laravel-auditing) package. Migrations created audit table. But when i update a model which is applied owen-it/laravel-auditing it's not updating the audit table.

my model is

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;
class BillingProgramme extends Model implements Auditable
{
     use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
}
```

my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "caffeinated/modules": "^4.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.4",
        "laravel/dusk": "^5.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/telescope": "~1.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "moontoast/math": "^1.1",
        "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^8.0.0",
        "paulvl/backup": "3.*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.11",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.3",
        "wildside/userstamps": "^0.5.5"
    },
```

if anyone note the issue please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use this library as well and works well for me like this;

```
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable as AuditableContract;

class ClassName extends Model implements AuditableContract{
 use Auditable;

 /**
   * Attributes to include in the Audit.
   *
   * @var array
   */

protected $auditInclude = [
    'WHATEVER YOU WANT TO AUDIT',
  ];

}
```